# Cannot SSH into host on local network using TCP wrappers, despite allowing "sshd : LOCAL" in /etc/hosts.allow

Tags: server, ssh, firewall

I have two servers running **ubuntu server 22.04.2 LTS** on my local network, the servers have the following names and IP addresses: `ubuntuserver100` - `192.168.50.100` and `ubuntuserver101` - `192.168.50.101` with the same user installed. Both have `openssh-server 1:8.9p1-3ubuntu0.1` installed.

I would like to restrict ssh access to `ubuntuserver100` to my local area network (`192.168.50.0/24`) only, using the legacy technology 'TCP wrappers'.

I added the following lines in the respective TCP wrapper files:

```
/etc/hosts.deny :
sshd: ALL

/etc/hosts.allow :
sshd: LOCAL
```

When I try to ssh from `ubuntuserver101` into `ubuntuserver100` it throws the following error:

```
thomasgrusz@ubuntuserver101:~$ ssh thomasgrusz@ubuntuserver100
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
Connection reset by 192.168.50.100 port 22
thomasgrusz@ubuntuserver101:~$
```

The man pages say:

```
 LOCAL  Matches any host whose name does not contain a dot character.
```

As the hostname I am trying to ssh in from is `ubuntuserver101` , I don't understand why I am blocked.

If I change the line in **/etc/hosts.allow** to `sshd 192.168.50.` everything works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: I suspect it's because the remote host doesn't even see the client hostname, only its LAN IP address - it would need to do some kind of reverse DNS or reverse mDNS lookup (which might well return a qualified hostname like `ubuntuserver100.local` anyhow). What do the variables `SSH_CLIENT` and `SSH_CONNECTION` contain when you are connected?

Comment: ```SSH_CLIENT``` contains ```192.168.50.101 60696 22``` and ```SSH_CONNECTION``` contains ```192.168.50.101 60696 192.168.50.100 22```